# Process compressed video capture frame on iOS

Tags: ios, avfoundation, coreml

here's my problem.

I'm working on a real-time machine learning software in which I process image returned by the camera.

I'd like to process compressed video frame instead of raw image from :

```
(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connecti
```

I tried to modify directly the input by not using AVCaptureSession sessionPreset to set manually the bitrate.

Only the changes made with the sessionPreset property actually change something.

1st question: Is it possible to have a `sampleBuffer` with 1280x720 resolution and 4Mb/s bitrate quality and not a specific config made with `sessionPreset`?

2nd question: if this is not possible, can I process at runtime compressed frame made by `AVAssetWriter`?

Thx for all

Polpot